# How can I detect the from state in UI-Router

Tags: angular-ui-router

I am using UI-Router to develop a web application. I have a piece of code looking something like this:

```
$transitions.onStart({}, function(transition){
    let toState = transition._targetState._identifier;
    let fromState = transition._fromState._identifier;//this doesn't work
})
```

As you can see, the transition object contains a property called `_targetState`, but doesn't seem to contain a property indicating the from state. So how can I detect the from state.

Comment: I think the hook that you are using is wrong instead use onSuccess. $transitions.onSuccess({}, function(transition) {
  console.log(
      "Successful Transition from " + transition.from().name +
      " to " + transition.to().name
  );
});                                                                                                                                      Refer this: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitionhooks

Comment: the use of the from() method is correct.

Comment: Great that it works!

Answer (score 0):

The methods `to()` and `from()` of the `transition` object are needed.

```
$transitions.onStart({}, function(transition){
    let toState = transition.to().name;
    let fromState = transition.from().name;
})
```